# Laptop Keyboard

Tags: laptop, drivers, keyboard, bios, dell-latitude

I have a dell latitude E6420 and it was working fine until last month I encountered a very strange problem. My laptop's keyboard stops working as soon as I exit the bios startup screen. Like, I can enter setup etc by pressing F12 and stuff but after I enter the bios menu, it just stops working for no reason. I have tried reinstalling windows and drivers but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried another (USB) keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work like normal in safemode? You can try taking the battery out and running it on the power cord instead.